# why is the input not properly taken by the program

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  int i, t , l[100] , b[100] ;

  scanf("%d",&t);

  for(i=0 ; i < t ; i++)
  {
    scanf("%d %d",&l[i],&b[i]);
  }

  for(i=0 ; i < t ; i++)
  {
    printf("%d %d",l[i],b[i]);
  }
}
```

Why is the program not taking proper input.

For example,
if t=2,l and b arrays should be scanned twice and printed twice. That's not happening.

Comment: you might find the code easier to understand when it's indented

Comment: Also, it's behavior clearly depends on the input file, so without seeing that file there's no way to debug it.

Comment: So what IS happening?

Comment: Try replacing `scanf("%d %d",&l[i],&b[i]);` with `scanf(" %d %d",&l[i],&b[i]);`.

Comment: I guess because of spaces in format string in `scanf()` -- `"%d %d"` --remove space once and Give a try.

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure you that you are provide the input in the proper format?

Comment: Works for me too. I think you'll need to add some sample input that doesn't work.

Comment: Input: `2 1 2 3 4`. Output: `1 23 4`. There's no space between `2` and `3`. Otherwise works fine.

Comment: @pinkpanther Er... not unless you're seeing answers I don't see.

Answer (score 0):

```
  for(i=0 ; i < t ; i++)
  {    
    scanf("%d%d",&l[i],&b[i]); //remove space
  }

  for(i=0 ; i < t ; i++)
  {
    printf("%d %d",l[i],b[i]);
    puts("");  //just adding a new line
  }
```

maybe you misunderstood the numbers
b[i] l[i+1] (prints together) as a single one.

Comment: @pinkpanther: how can i delete OP question? [i guess i don't 've enough reputation]

Answer (score 0):

This program expects first an integer *d* that defines how many elements will be scanned and, then printed, in both arrays *l* and *b*.

Session example:

```
3
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

Output

```
1 23 45 6
```

You may want to add a `\n` in printf

```
printf("%d %d\n",l[i],b[i]);
```

to get that output

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

But besides, the output of that program seems to be consistent with what is expected, at first glance, to come from it, after reading the code. There doesn't seem to be a big bug (until you try to input data for a *d* > 100 - from the 101th element the program will have an unexpected behavior).

If the output does not fit your expectations, the program has to be modified accordingly. Maybe you can tell us what kind of output you want based on the input above, and we'll provide solutions.